# How to initialize list in form application

Tags: c#

I'm just begginer in programming and have one question. There is a code of my Windows form app:

```
namespace Temperature_controller.Temperature_controller
{
    public class CPU_Temp
    {
        public double CurrentValue { get; set; }

        public static List<CPU_Temp> Temperatures
        {
            get
            {
                List<CPU_Temp> result = new List<CPU_Temp>();
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature");
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Double temp = Convert.ToDouble(obj["CurrentTemperature"].ToString());
                    temp = (temp - 2732) / 10.0;
                    result.Add(new CPU_Temp { CurrentValue = temp });

                }
                return result;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

there is a form code:

```
namespace Temperature_controller
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CPU_Temp cPU_Temp = new CPU_Temp();

            cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Values=new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>
                    {
                        new ObservablePoint(0,cPU_Temp.CurrentValue),
                        new ObservablePoint(0,cPU_Temp.CurrentValue),
                        new ObservablePoint(0,cPU_Temp.CurrentValue),
                        new ObservablePoint(0,cPU_Temp.CurrentValue)
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how can I initialize the list? I don't know how to call it. I do not owe this code just found it in internet and have tried to fit to my project but it was writning i think to console application and i have no idea how to change it to work in Windows Form. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You already initialize a list right here: `new List<CPU_Temp>()`  What exactly isn't working?  It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: I think its better to tell us what you want to accomplish and what is the problem you are having. I don't think you addressed the question properly. Anyway to get your temperature list you should call var any_variable_name = CPU_Temp.Temperatures;
 Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to send field CurrentValue to form(new ObservablePoint(0,cPU_Temp.CurrentValue),)  but this field is always empty so i susposed that public static List<CPU_Temp> Temperatures is empty to. My question is how can i fill this list.

Comment: @ThisWorldNeedHope: *"i susposed that public static List<CPU_Temp> Temperatures is empty to"* - Do you *assume* that or did you *observe* that in some way?  If you're just making assumptions without testing them then we can't help with that.  `CurrentValue` is empty because you're not setting a value to it anywhere.  `Temperatures` will return whatever values it dynamically reads in the code within that property.  If it returns an empty list then there were no values to read.  To "fill that list" you would need to populate whatever external data it's reading.

Comment: I thought that this part of code is responsible of set the value of CurrentValue
"result.Add(new CPU_Temp { CurrentValue = temp });"

Comment: @ThisWorldNeedHope: That sets the value on the instance of `CPU_Temp` added to that list.  But not on any other instance.  As an analogy, imagine that you drive your car to a car factory.  In that car factory you observe the assembly line always putting an item in the trunk of every car it builds.  So you open the trunk of the car you drove there, but you don't find that item in your trunk.  Why?  Because your car and the cars in the factory are different cars.  They look the same, they have the same features, but they're not the same car.

Comment: I do understand and many thanks for your replies but could you describe what can i do to make this app working properly ?

Answer (score 0):

When you did this:
List result = new List();

You initialized your list. I would just put it outside the curly brackets ; this way you’ll always have an empty list initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is List.Clear() function.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2).